# Whitelabel Error page, Type:Not Found Status:404

Tags: maven, spring-boot, java-8, swagger-2.0

We recently upgraded our spring boot version from 1.5.10 to 2.1.2 and I'm facing an issue. When the service is deployed on j boss server, it says service Not found and throws an error of White label error page when I call the service in the swagger by https://host:port/serviceName/swagger-ui.html but if i call https://host:port/swagger-ui.html I could access the service and everything works fine. Can some one let me know what will be the issue. Appreciated for the help.

There is nothing change in the pom.xml or bootstrap.yml, I have just upgraded the spring boot versions. Everything else is same as previous.

> Below is the POM.Xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.goo.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <properties>
        <dep.scope>compile</dep.scope>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <ojdbc.version>12.1.0.2</ojdbc.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <springfox-version>2.6.1</springfox-version>
        <config.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</config.version>
        <admin.version>2.1.0</admin.version>
        <consul-starter.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</consul-starter.version>
        <cloud-consul.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</cloud-consul.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${cloud-consul.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
            <scope>${dep.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
            <scope>${dep.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>${dep.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Consul properties -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
            <version>${consul-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring config server - external properties -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>${config.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot admin client - monitoring the purpose -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>${admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--  jedis cache  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you "lost" your `context-path`. I guess you previously specified it using the now deprecated `server.contextPath=/serviceName` in some form. There are several ways to set it, but the way I do it is configuring it in the `application.yaml`

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: serviceName
```

or `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/serviceName
```

or you could set the context-path by specifying it as a command line argument

```
java -jar app.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/serviceName
```

This is just some of the options available. Figure out how you set it before and replace that with `server.servlet.context-path`

Comment: There is a property in my bootstrap.yml with feild 
 "spring:
  application:
    name: "

That checks with the application name.

Comment: I would try to `server: servlet: context-path: serviceName` to set the `context-path` specifically and see if that works